# Como incluir um valor na última linha de um data.frame no R

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho um data.frame e um valor no R, precisava que este valor fosse incluído na última linha de determinada coluna deste data.frame. Já testei a função `rbind` mas não funcionou.

```
x <- c(1:15)
y <- c(1:15)
z <- 4
df <- data.frame(x,y)
df <- rbind(x, z)
```

Comment: A pergunta não está bem formulada. Qual é a resposta esperada para ela, já que `df` possui duas colunas e `z` possui apenas uma observação? A última linha deve ser formada por `c(4, 4)`? Ou `c(NA, 4)`? Ou ainda `c(4, NA)`? Por favor, verifique isso e seja mais claro a respeito de suas necessidades.

Comment: Perdão, o valor de Z deveria ser incluído na última linha de X, portanto, c(4, NA)

Comment: Mas `x` só tem uma dimensão. Por acaso `c(4, NA)` deveria ser a última linha de `df`?

Comment: Sim, o df deveria ficar com 16 linhas, e a última ser c(4, NA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie o data frame `z` com as observações desejadas, atentando para que os nomes de suas colunas condigam com os nomes das colunas de `df`:

```
x <- c(1:15)
y <- c(1:15)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
names(df)
# [1] "x" "y"

z <- data.frame(x = 4, y = NA)
df <- rbind(df, z)
df
#     x  y
# 1   1  1
# 2   2  2
# 3   3  3
# 4   4  4
# 5   5  5
# 6   6  6
# 7   7  7
# 8   8  8
# 9   9  9
# 10 10 10
# 11 11 11
# 12 12 12
# 13 13 13
# 14 14 14
# 15 15 15
# 16  4 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar valores em quaisquer posições diretamente, não é necessário criar um objeto só para isso:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:15,
                 y = 1:15)

df[nrow(df)+1, "x"] <- 4

> tail(df)
    x  y
11 11 11
12 12 12
13 13 13
14 14 14
15 15 15
16  4 NA
```

Se a posição já existir, o valor é substituído. Se não, o data.frame é redimensionado e NAs inseridos por omissão.